# Comma separated string of selected values horizontally in MySQL

Tags: mysql, string, select

I want to convert selected values horizontally into a comma separated string in MySQL.

The query is:

`SELECT user_a, user_b, user_c FROM tb_loterijos_laimetojai`

[image]

My desired output would look like this (in one string):

```
Admin, Admin, Admin
Admin, Admin, Admin
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Just because you *can*, it doesn't follow that you *should*

Comment: Can you explain more, please?

Comment: I think Gordon covered it in his final paragraph.

Comment: Oh, I understand. No, that is correct. Admin is just an example, every name would be different than Admin :) There are user_a, user_b and user_c because there are 3 places to win.

Comment: What if there were four places? Would there be four columns? This is poor design.

Comment: What should I use instead? Using different design I would not be able to determine the winner.

Comment: Of course you would

Comment: So, how? :) I am not good at MySQL like you, explain, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `concat_ws()`:

```
select concat_ws(',', user_a, user_b, user_c)
```

Note that having multiple columns with the same reference is generally an anti-pattern.  You should probably have another table with one row per whatever and user.

Comment: Thank you, it worked :) What is wrong if it is anti-pattern?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT CONCAT(user_a, ",", user_b, ",", user_c) FROM tb_loterijos_laimetojai
```

Comment: Actually, just seen Gordon answer and it's better.

Answer (score 1):

Use `concat()` mysql function

```
SELECT CONCAT(user_a, ",", user_b, ",", user_c) as user FROM tb_loterijos_laimetojai
```